# How to track sent WebServices response progress

Tags: web-services, jersey, inputstream, tracking, progress

I am using HTTPClient on my client app to send a GET request to my Jersey RESTful web service. 
what is the best way to track how many bytes have been received on the server side?  should I make a web service call within my while loop below to notify the server after
a certain certain number of bytes have been received up until it's finished?

```
InputStream inputStream = resp.getEntity().getContent();

byte data[] = new byte[8096];
int count;
int total = 0;

while ((count = inputStream.read(data, 0, 8096)) != -1) {
               //best way to notify server of received bytes?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be the way. But you should do it asynchronously (i.e. by notifying the server on a separate thread) so that you don't slow down the file reading by waiting for server's response to the progress notification.